# Filter for servlet doesn't work

Tags: java, servlets, web-deployment, servlet-filters

I would like to use a filter for one specific servlet. My code is:

```
     @WebFilter(dispatcherTypes = {
            DispatcherType.REQUEST, 
            DispatcherType.FORWARD, 
            DispatcherType.INCLUDE
    }
                , servletNames = { "myServlet" })
    public class ImageProtect implements Filter 
    {
          public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException 
          {
          System.out.println("Hello from Filter");
          chain.doFilter(request, response);
         }
    }
```

My problem is that nothing happens. In the eclipse console Cant see the message unfortunately. The servlet is just a stock servlet. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this filter in web.xml file

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>ImageProtect</filter-name>
   <filter-class>ImageProtect</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>ImageProtect</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/myServlet</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I don't even have one. I don't know whether this matter or not but it is a maven project.

Comment: You should, in the root of your project (where you put all your jsp files etc) you should have a `WEB-INF/web.xml` file

Comment: This article said that I don't need to do anything with a web.xml to have this work. Are they lying then? http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-java-servlet-filter

Comment: And I also have my filter work which filters specific jsp files not servlers without even having web.xml file

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this work without using web.xml, you need to write FQCN for servletNames in stead of just the servlet name, "myServlet".
If your "myServlet" file is in a package "xxx.xxxx.xxxx", then
 not "myServlet", but "xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.myServlet".
Then the filter should work.

Comment: If you prefer to configure your WebFilters not in web.xml, then this solution works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should try mapping this filter to every web pages  `@WebFilter("/*")` just try adding this in your annotation instead of mapping your filter to one specific servlet which is `servletNames = { "myServlet" }`.I guess this might help you out